# Open modal drop down using onPress for react-native-modal-dropdown

Tags: javascript, react-native, dropdown, onpress

I am having issues with the "TouchableOpacity" "onPress". When I click on it, nothing happens.
I made it as a component so I can call it from app.js.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

Here is my code:

```
const DropDownBox = () => {
 
  const [SelectedValue, SetSelectedValue] = useState(-1);

  function ComboBox() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}> 
        <ModalDropdown
          options={LeavesData}
          defaultValue="Please Select Leave"
          style={styles.dropdownContainer}
          textStyle={styles.DropdownText}
          dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownbox}
          onSelect={SetSelectedValue}
        >
        </ModalDropdown>
    </View>
    )
  }


  //Index to Value
  var Value = "";
  Value = LeavesData[SelectedValue];

  return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => ComboBox()} > 
              <Text style={styles.dropdownContainer}>Please Select</Text>
           
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.displayText} >{Value} selected </Text>

        </View>
  )
}

export default DropDownBox;
```

Comment: at first test add ModalDropdown directly in your main view . if it's work in second delete top view in your function and test again

Comment: @MeisamSaba what do u mean by delete top view?

Comment: ComboBox function just return dromdown and remove parent view . and test that